# Why does make stop with "Makefile:6: *** multiple target patterns. Stop."?

Tags: make, gnu-make

**Goal** I write my slides in a markdown file and compile it to reveal afterwards, uploading it to my webserver and do other things. I wanted to organise the steps after the markdown is written in a makefile:

```
PROJNAME = `pwd | grep -oP '(\w|-)+' | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

presentation: slides.pandoc
    pandoc --self-contained --data-dir=$(HOME)/.pandoc --template=slides/revealjs_niels_tmpl.html -V revealjs-url:$(HOME)/.pandoc/revealjs -V theme:solarized slides.pandoc -f markdown -t revealjs -o $(PROJNAME).html

onlinepresent: $(PROJNAME).html
    cp $(PROJNAME).html $(HOME)/Share/index.html
```

**Explanation** `PROJNAME` looks for the project folder name and converts it to lowercase. In the example folder where I am using it and which generates the message shown in the Title, this results in `ws-anno-ii`. The `presentation` rule compiles the slides as html by using `pandoc`. The `PROJNAME` Macro is used to define the name of the output file. `onlinepresent` where `make` is stopping should copy a file which holds the project name (`ws-anno-ii.html`) if this file exists to a mounted external filesystem (`Share`). If it does not exist, of course the `presentation` rule should apply first. But when I put the `make` command nothing happens, and I get the message

The `make` process stops with `Makefile:6: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.` referring to the line `onlinepresent: $(PROJNAME).html`

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the make variable `PROJNAME` is

```
`pwd | grep -oP '(\w|-)+' | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
```

The backquote character is not special in make. If you use the variable in a shell command, the shell sees the backquotes and parses them as a command substitution. But if you use the variable in a place where it's interpreted by make, the backquotes don't do anything special. The line `onlinepresent: $(PROJNAME).html` becomes, after variable expansion,

```
onlinepresent: `pwd | grep -oP '(\w|-)+' | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`.html
```

which make parses as `onlinepresent`, colon, `` `pwd ``, `\`, `grep`, `-oP`, `'(\w|-)+'`, `|`, `tail`, `-n`, `2`, `|`, `head`, `-n`, `1`, `|`, `tr`, `'[`, colon, `upper`, colon, `]'`, `'[`, colon, `lower`, colon, `` ]'`.html ``. There are multiple words to the left of the rightmost colon, hence “multiple target patterns”.

If you want to use the output of a shell command in a place where make will read it, you need to invoke the [`shell` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function). This is a GNU make feature, it won't work in other make implementations.

```
PROJNAME = $(shell pwd | grep -oP '(\w|-)+' | tail -n 2 | head -n 1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`)
```

This sets the `PROJNAME` variable to the next-to-last component of working directory transformed to lowercase.

Note that using the current directory is fragile: it means your makefile won't work if invoked from a different directory as the target. It would be more robust to compute `PROJNAME` from the path to the target. If it wasn't for the lowercase part, you could do it entirely (if cumbersomely) with make functions (I assume that the intent of your splitting code is really to extract pathname components):

```
$(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(abspath $@))))))
```

but GNU make doesn't have a case conversion facility. If you're going to invoke a shell anyway, you can make it simpler.

```
PROJNAME = $(shell set -x; echo '$(abspath $@)' | awk -F/ '{$$0=tolower($$0); print $$(NF-2)}')
onlinepresent: $(PROJNAME).html
        cp $< $$HOME/Share/index.html
```

Note the use of `$$` in the makefile which becomes `$` in the shell commands. This works because the `PROJNAME` variable is calculated on each use, not at the time of definition (variable definitions in make are expanded on each use if they use `=`, and when the assignment is read if they use `:=`).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `make onlinepresent`, `make` goes to the target `onlinepresent` and sees that it requires `$(PROJNAME).html`, which is kind of *wrong* ... from the point of view of make, because there is no target providing directly `$(PROJNAME).html`.

I am also assuming that your assignment of `PROJNAME` has only **one possible** result.

Try with

```
presentation: slides.pandoc
#your pandoc rule
onlinepresent: presentation
#your mv command
```

This tells `make` that in order to make the target `onlinepresent`, the target `presentation` is required. Then the target presentation tells make that `slides.pandoc` is required, so it will run the rule if `slides.pandoc` is new or has been modified.

**OR**

You can also try renaming the target `presentation` to `$(PROJNAME).html` instead, so that it looks like

```
$(PROJNAME).html: slides.pandoc
#your pandoc rule
onlinepresent: $(PROJNAME).html
#your mv command
```

Comment: The first solution does always use both rules, even if there were no changes made since the last make process.
 / 
The second solutions complains with: Makefile:3: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

Comment: from the most voted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113138/target-pattern-contains-no-makefile: This is a badly written error message from Make. It means "one of your filenames had a character that could be part of a regular expression" ... so check your variable contents to be sure that Make is not getting something wrong.
The fact that the "presentation" target is always executed even if no change was done to the file confuses me... are your sure that `pandoc` does not alter in anyway (not even `touch` the file?)

Comment: Thank you! I had already a look at the stackoverflow question you mention. The Str which is generated in the example for `PROJNAME` is *'ws-anno-ii'*. I already tried to add `| tr '-' '\-'` to the line where `PROJNAME` is defined following the advice from the stackoverflow question but this does not change anything, still the same error. / In the `presentation` solution the dependent file for the `presentation` rule is `slides.pandoc`. It was modified yesterday evening for the last time following `ls`. B the way `make` is **GNU Make 4.1**

Comment: I now tried the makefile with the `PROJNAME` resulting in `wsannoii`, so no character that can be interpreted as a regular expression and still I get the same result. Is it possible that it is not allowed to use macros for a target?

Comment: You can use variables as target name, see here https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html